# Pattern matching implementing Lambda calculus in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, lambda-calculus

I want to write a function that will collect the variable names that have been used in a lambda calculus term, both as a Variable and in a Lambda abstraction.

For example in the code I would get the following output:

```
  *Main> used example
         ["a","b","x","y"]
```

I want to return them in an ordered list. I think I could achieve this using pattern matching and wild cards, is this possible?

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term

example :: Term
example = Lambda "a" (Lambda "x" (Apply (Apply (Lambda "y" (Variable "a"))
                                               (Variable "x"))
                                        (Variable "b")))

-- I'll use this function to merge two ordered lists together:

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y    = x : merge xs ys
    | x <= y    = x : merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys

used :: Term -> [Var]
used [] = []
used Variable_ = _
used Lambda_ = _
used Apply_ = _
```

This is clearly not correct.

How do I collect the variable names and add them to a list? If pattern matching and wild cards are not correct, please can you suggest how I could go about this?

Comment: Why do you think that it's clearly not correct? Are you getting an error or an incorrect result? If so, what are they?

Comment: Your cases for `used` look wrong. `[]` is not a term, remove that case. The others should read `used (Variable v) = ...`, `used (Lambda v t) = ...`, and `used (Apply t1 t2) = ...`. Note how you write a pattern for each term constructor, with the right amount of variables.

Comment: This is the error message list.hs:28:6: error:
    `Not in scope: data constructor ‘Apply_’
    Perhaps you meant ‘Apply’ (line 9)` I think this leads back to what @chi said about the term constructor. Also I now don't think a wild card is what I should be using, as I think wild cards are used when you don't care about the result, whereas I want to collect the result of the pattern matching. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: Like this @chi @FyodorSoikin ? `used :: Term -> [Var], used (Variable v) = x, used (Lambda v t) = x.x, used (Apply t1 t2) = x x` I am still not pattern matching correctly, as I get this error `list.hs:26:23: error: Variable not in scope: x :: a0 -> b0
   |
26 | used (Lambda v t) = x.x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `used` is a function `Term -> [Var]`.  And so to write `used` in a pattern matching style, we'll need to make a case for each of the different ways to be a `Term`.  Looking at the definition of `Term` we see there are 3 ways to be a `Term`: by being a variable, a lambda, or an apply.  In particular being an empty list (`[]`) is not a way to be a `Term`, so that case should be removed.

Next lets look at the syntax of pattern matching.  It should look like the following:

```
used :: Term -> [Var]
used (Variable var) = ...
used (Lambda var term) = ...
used (Apply term1 term2) = ...
```

Note the parenthesis around each set of data constructor and arguments.  Also note that variables in Haskell must start with lowercase characters.  Finally note that we haven't actually written any of the bodies of the cases for `used`.  The above is not actually valid Haskell.

Let's go over how to fill in all the right hand sides of these cases.  While we do so let's keep in mind that `used` is meant to return an ordered list of `Var` without repeats. Most of that isn't captured in the type of `used`.

#### The `Variable` case:

```
used (Variable var) = ...
```

So the right hand side here has to be a list of `Var`.  Checking the declaration of `Term` and the `Variable` case, we see that `var` must be a `Var`.  Thus, really the only option for the implementation is:

```
used (Varable var) = [var]
```

#### The `Lambda` case

```
used (Lambda var term) = ...
```

So again checking the type declaration of `Term` we see that `var` is a `Var` and `term` is a `Term`. Maybe that's why we used those variable names ;). So some variables appear in `var` and some variables appear in `term`.  If we knew all of those variables we could put those results together with `merge`.  For `var` we can do the same thing as in the `Variable` case.  For `term` we need a way to turn a `Term` into a variable or a list of variables.  Luckily we have such a way.  It's the function we're currently defining: `used`!  So we can write this case as:

```
used (Lambda var term) = merge [var] (used term)
```

It might look a bit silly to use `merge` to merge a singleton list into another list, but we need to keep the result ordered and `merge` is the hammer we have so we turned this problem into a nail.

#### The `Apply` case

This case will go quite quickly using the same idea as above.  We have

```
used (Apply term1 term2) = ...
```

`term1` and `term2` are `Term`'s.  We'll extract the variables from each of them using `used` and merge them together using `merge`.

```
used (Apply term1 term2) = merge (used term1) (used term2)
```

Overall this gives the implementation of `used`:

```
used :: Term -> [Var]
used (Variable var) = [var]
used (Lambda var term) = merge [var] (used term)
used (Apply term1 term2) = merge (used term1) (used term2)
```

with

```
  *Main> used example
         ["a","b","x","y"]
```

as desired.